# wordpress get_comments исключить комментарии из определенной рубрики

Tags: wordpress

В wordpress получаю список всех комментариев через функцию `get_comments();` как мне исключить из выборки те комментарии ID категории которых 13?

Comment: У комментариев нет категорий, что за ерунду вы спрашиваете?

Answer (score 1):

```
$posts = get_posts( [
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'category'    => 13,
    'fields'      => 'ids',
] );

$comments = get_comments( [
   'post__not_in' => $posts
] );
```